# How to deal with: "The Crashlytics build ID is missing"

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crashlytics

I'm writing a xamarin app where I need to use Crashlytics but upon install while following [This guide](https://medium.com/@freakyali/firebase-crashlytics-for-maui-and-xamarin-19938cc24f81) I've found that when I try to run the Android app I get:

```
Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

```
[FirebaseApp] Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
[FirebaseCrashlytics] Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.3.2 for com.lorem.ipsum
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  | 
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  |
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  |
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .   \ |  | /
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .    \    /
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     \  /
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .      \/
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .
[FirebaseCrashlytics] The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .      /\
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     /  \
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .    /    \
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .   / |  | \
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  |
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  |
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .     |  |
[FirebaseCrashlytics] .
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
**Java.Lang.RuntimeException:** 'Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.'
```

every time no matter what I do.

Also on the iOS side of things if I try to run this code:

```
Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
                Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SendUnsentReports();
```

The app crashes.

On android I've tried the whole string thing. I've made the String.xml inside of app.Android/Resources/values/ and written inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">2.0</string>
    <string name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id">none</string>
    <string name="google_app_id">The "current_key" from the google-servicies.json</string>
</resources>
```

The google-servicies.json is correct and on the root folder and I've made sure to have all the nuGet packages installed but to no avail. Nothing I've found has worked for me.

On the iOS front I haven't made that much of a labor as I was preoccupied with the Android part that now doesn't work in general.

### EDIT:

One note I must say is that this project is supposed to substitute one from android studio that already had crashlytics installed and both share the same package name. (This does not apply to the iOS counterpart that is completely new)

### EDIT 2:

I managed to solve the Android front where I needed to add:

```
<GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
```

To my .Android.csproj

Now on the iOS part I've managed to get the logs which for some reason before didn't show up and they say:

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Callstack: '  at diarioDeTeruelIOS.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00021] in C:\App.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:31
```

Where

```
Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SendUnsentReports();
```

is. This time I've checked the csproj, and the .plist, I have the crashlytics and the firabase.core NuGet packages.

Comment: Can you add the versions you are using to build your project? Android Studio version, Xamarin version, Firebase Crashlytics version, etc. Sometimes some versions used are very outdated in some cases.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
Xamarin 17.5.0.173
NuGets:
Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics 118.3.2.1
Xamarin.Firebase.Common 120.2.0.1
Also see the post I've made and edit.

Comment: Forgot to say my target framework is .NET Standard 2.1
Android Min sdk 19 Target sdk 32

Comment: You can try [`<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">1</string>`](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/642#issuecomment-1221520982) in this issue about 
[The Crashlytics build ID is missing](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/642) on the github.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Tried that one of the first things and didn't work, it turned out to be a missing thing inside the App.Android.csproj. Now the android front isn't crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my Strings.xml resources file to resolve the issue:

```
<resources>
    <string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">none</string>
</resources>
```